# Python parsing large CSV file for usernames

Tags: python, csv, large-files

I have a very large csv file (+50k lines).

This file contains IRC logs and here's the data format:

- 1st column: Message type (1 for message, 2 for system)
- 2nd column: Timestamps (numbers of seconds since a precise date)
- 3rd column: Username of the one writing the message
- 4th column: Message

Here's an example of the data:

```
1,1382445487956,"bob","i don't know how to do such a task"
1,1382025765196,"alice","bro ask stackoverflow"
1,1382454875476,"_XxCoder_killerxX_","I'm pretty sure it can be done with python, bob"
2,1380631520410,"helloman","helloman_ join the chan."
```

For example, `_XxCoder_killerxX_` mentioned `bob`.

So, knowing all of this, I want to know which pair of usernames mentioned each others the most.
I want **messages** to be count, so I only need to work on lines starting with the number "1" (as there is a bunch of lines starting with "2" and other irrelevant numbers)

I know it can be done with the `csv` Python module, but I've never worked with such larges files so I really don't know how to start all of this.

Comment: Do you know how to work with small files?

Comment: I'd say I'll save all usernames into dict and then check all messages to find if there is any mention of someone and then I'll have to count them out to find the one with the greatest number ?

Comment: Yes... have you tried it? Was there a problem?

Comment: Yes I've been trying but I can't think of a way of storing data, I know how to store all usernames but not how to count the numbers of times pair usernames were mentionning each others

Comment: This would be super easy using `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform two passes of the CSV: one to capture all sender usernames, the second to find sender usernames mentioned in messages.

```
import csv

users = set()

with open("test.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        users.add(line[2])

mentions = {}

with open("test.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        sender, message = line[2], line[3]
        for recipient in users:
            if recipient == sender:
                continue  # can't mention yourself
            if recipient in message:
                key = (sender, recipient)
                mentions[key] = mentions.get(key, 0) + 1

for mention, times in mentions.items():
    print(f"{mention[0]} mentioned {mention[1]} {times} time(s)")


totals = {}

for mention, times in mentions.items():
    key = tuple(sorted(mention))
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + times

for names, times in totals.items():
    print(f"{names[0]} and {names[1]} mentioned each other {times} time(s)")
```

This example is naive, as it's performing simple substring matches. So, if there's someone named "foo" and someone mentions "food" in a message, it will indicate a match.

Comment: Wow, almost done, how do I know the pair of the usernames that mentionned each other the most now ?

Comment: Added code in example above. I'll leave it to you to find the largest count.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit! But it seems your code gives me self mentionning result such as `bob bob mentioned each other X time(s)`

Comment: I've improved the code to suppress mentioning yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the work! Problem is that your code count mention from system message whereas I need only to count mention thing from message (lines starting with the number "1" only) as in my main post I said I want mention from usernames not from the system itself

Comment: Feel free to enhance the example to meet your unique needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pandas and sets.  The use of pandas significantly simplifies the import and manipulation of csv data, and the use of sets allows one to count {'alice', 'bob'} and {'bob', 'alice'} as two occurrences of the same combination.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['id','timestamp','username','message']

lst = []
for name in df.username:
    for i,m in enumerate(df.message):
        if name in m:
            author = df.iloc[i,2]
            lst.append({author, name})
most_freq = max(lst, key=lst.count)

print(most_freq)
#{'bob', '_XxCoder_killerxX_'}
```

Comment: If you are going to do this you really shouldn't be using `pandas` at all. Also, `most_freq = max(lst, key=lst.count)` is very inefficient.

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea to use pandas ? Someone else also told me to use pandas

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use pandas. I think what he means is that I am not using the full capabilities of a pandas dataframe because I am iterating through its columns.  In this case, I am using the dataframe simply to store the data.

Comment: Your solution seems good but I've got an odd error : `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 731, saw 5` and the line 731 is : `1,1380877652084,"Lukaaas","\"nine times what it has to be, no\""`

Comment: It looks like line 731 in your csv file is corrupt because of too many double-quotes.  Either delete it or change it to 1,1380877652084,"Lukaaas","\'nine times what it has to be, no\'"

Comment: Just another one question, is it possible for pandas not to read_csv but read a variable containing a whole csv as a dict ? It would resolve this issue as I can't edit the inputed CSV

Comment: Yes. df = pd.Dataframe(your_dict)

Comment: You can also try df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None, skiprows=[731]).  Play around with the number.  Try 730 or 732 if 731 does not work.  Also if you get erros messages about other corrupt lines, you can skip them by skiprows = [731, 921,...].

Comment: Don’t forget to accept the answer if it worked for you. That was a lot of work.